# 504-Gateway Timeout [Python]

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to add Vietnamese accent based on API on the web( [link](https://docs.openfpt.vn/#api-add-accents))

However, the response was 504-Gateway Timeout. Here is the code:

```
import requests
url = "http://api.openfpt.vn/vnaccent/add"

headers = {

'api_key': "****************",
'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
}
payload = {'text': 'do la mot nguoi dan ba dam dang'}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to post your API key in a public forum. Additionally you should separately try to verify that the site you're trying to use is actually up or not.

Comment: On the other hand, without a valid API key we probably can't do anything to troubleshoot this. 504 is general enough that it could be a code problem or a server-side problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not fix it since [504](https://httpstatuses.com/504) is not your problem but server side.